# Пустое поле TextView Android

Tags: android, listview, activity, textview

Здравствуйте. Только начал изучать программирование под Андроид и столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда парсил сайт на андроид-устройстве: Получаю ЛистВью со ссылками на новости, перехожу по одной из них, текст с новостью попадает в ТекстВью и прекрасно отображается на экране устройства, но после нажатия кнопки "Назад" и переходе на новую новость получается пустой экран. Как-будто ничего в новости не написано. После перезапуска проекта опять работает отображение любой новости, по которой тапнул, дальше пусто. Код прилагается.
Буду рад любой подсказке. Огромное спасибо.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listItem;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItem);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
    parseTitle.execute();

    try {
        final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = parseTitle.get();
        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet()){
            arrayList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

        listItem.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ParseText parseText = new ParseText();
                parseText.execute(hashMap.get(arrayList.get(i)));

                try {
                    listItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setText(parseText.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    listItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

class ParseText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String str = "";
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(voids[0]).get();
            Element element = document.select(".article__title").first();
            str = element.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}

class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HashMap<String, String>>{
    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(String... voids) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://korrespondent.net/").get();
            Elements elements = document.select(".article ");

            for (Element element : elements){
                Element element1 = element.select("a[href]").first();
                hashMap.put(element.text(), element1.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hashMap;
    }
}
}
```

Код брал из видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCo_1nsxeY0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда отрабатывает код 
`public void onBackPressed() {
    listItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}` - Вы скрываете свой textView и при выборе следующей новости, Вы не обновляете видимость этого элемента.
Попробуйте изменить видимость этого элемента при клике на элемент списка:
`......
                try {
                    listItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView.setText(parseText.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
....`

Comment: Не сработало... =(

Comment: Прошу меня извинить.
Все великолепно работает. По запарке не в то место строку дописал.
Спасибо огромное!